# Why laravel Auth::attempt not working

Tags: php, laravel

Spent last 30 minutes reading all posts on stackoverflow about this. Can't find solution.
This is my code:

```
public function PostLogIn(Request $request)
    {

      if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {

              return redirect()->route('dashboard');
          }
      $status = 'Incorrect details';
      return view('login')->with('status',$status);

    }
```

Before you ask, i'm saving user password in hash on registration and password column can accept all 60 characters. I'm using standard user model with default names for email and password fields.
Read somewhere that i should add this to user model:

```
  public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->UserEmail;
}
```

Tried also don't work. From is sending data properly but my auth still fails for some reason.

(I created post 1.5 hours ago, wanted to edit but deleted by accident, sorry for the guy who replied :) )

Comment: What do `$request->email` and `$request->password` contain? Do they have what you expect them to have?

Comment: They contain data from form input. Yes i did dd() on $request and it's fine !

Comment: Try by removing `getAuthPassword` function.

Answer (score 0):

I can comment yet, but if this doesn't help you I'll remove it.

1. Make sure `$request->email` brings anything (the email), `dd($request->email);`
2. Same for `$request->password`
3. Check if `$request->password` produces same hash that the one in DB:

   ```
   if (Hash::check($request->password, $hashInDB)) {
       // The passwords match...
   }
   ```
4. Finally (actualy this should be done first :P) check if the email on `$request->email` is the same as the one you have stored in DB

PS: not sure about `getAuthPassword` in the model, you should try to do the attempt without it